# Can mod_rewrite secure cookies?

Tags: security, http, mod-rewrite, cookies, https

Say you only want to send cookies over HTTPS to the client - not over HTTP. You could use the HTTP secure flags as mentioned in [this](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/securing-cookies-httponly-secure-flags/) article. However, since you can use the Apache mod_rewrite module to send a redirect to the user from the HTTP version of your site to the HTTPS version, shouldn't that mean that it will secure the cookies? In other words, does the server send your cookies if its sending out a redirect?

Comment: Interesting. I am actually not quite sure.

Comment: Secure cookies are entirely client-based. The web browser will only send cookies marked as such if it believes it is connecting using HTTPS.

Comment: I'm kind of confused here. mod_rewrite redirections from HTTP to HTTPS generally involve sending a `Location` header when connecting without SSL. This tells the client to reconnect using HTTPS. At no point does mod_rewrite have any control of the `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: @Phylogenesis mod_rewrite has the `[CO=...]` flag that can set a cookie. ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS and then set cookies, these cookies will be set over HTTPS. Say you redirect the user from `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, the `Set-Cookie` header sent from `www.example.com` to the user will be encrypted during transport.

However, if the user comes back and enters `http://www.example.com` in their browser, if the [Secure Flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) was not set on the cookie, the cookie will be sent over HTTP, unencrypted.

This can also happen if any internal links on your site are HTTP, any links on other sites to yours are HTTP or if a MITM attacker injects a HTTP resource from your site on another site (e.g. `<img src="http://www.example.com/x.jpg" />` will leak the cookie over HTTP).

This is why it is advisable to set the secure flag. [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) can be used to help ensure connections remain on HTTPS only, however setting the secure flag should be the primary focus.